# FullCalendar : how does it calculate the date values?

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

When using the FullCalendar with default settings it uses the current date by default and will send data to my server-side script - which happens here:

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback)
```

the dates being sent:

```
current date: 2019-05-14
fullcalender is sending: 
2019-05-27 - 2019-07-08

when skipping to june it is sending:
2019-05-27 - 2019-07-08 (which would be +28 days from the current date)

when skipping to july it is sending:
2019-07-01 - 2019-08-12
```

i need to code a debug script which uses the same date ranges for testing purposes - but can't find out out how the calendar is calculating the variables start and end, any ideas? doesn't make sense to me ..

thanks

Comment: Looks like it is using Mondays and requesting a partial week from the previous month and at least a full week from the next month.

Answer (score 0):

It's based on what is going to be visible in the newly selected view and date range. Take a look at the [demo](https://fullcalendar.io/) and look at the month view.

In a standard month view, because it always uses a grid with 7 columns, you can see that when you are displaying June 2019 for example, there are a few days from May and a few days from July visible at either end in order to complete the grid. (Exactly which days they are will depend on your locale setting and whether it affects what is considered the first day of the week.)

Hence fullCalendar will request events to cover all those dates and ensure events are displayed for all the days which are visible in the grid.

If it just requested the exact days in the month, it would appear that no events were taking place in those other visible days. That might potentially be incorrect if in reality there are events scheduled for those dates.

If you wish, you can set the [showNonCurrentDates](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/showNonCurrentDates) setting to `true` to suppress this behaviour.